# vBulletin: Check if user read thread externally

Tags: php, vbulletin

Is there any possible way to check if a user who is logged in has read a certain thread? I'm currently using a seperate webpage (outside of the forum software) where I need to check if a user is logged in and if this user has read a certain thread. I've gotten to check if a user logged in or not by requiring global.php, but I am not sure how to check if the user read the thread.

I'm using PHP on this webpage and would preferably like to stick to it (which shouldn't be difficult since vBulletin is built in PHP)

Edit: using vBulletin 4.2.0

Thanks!

Comment: save the thread id within an array in a table. then write a script on the thread page to check whether the thread id exists in the array. if not add it

Comment: Doesn't vBulletin do this already? I mean, it knows when you've read a thread, according to the icons displayed in the index, so I would think this would be easier than that.

Comment: Sorry i didn't realise you was using vBulletin. ill check it out

Comment: Do you code the php yourself or is it a plugin style of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by reading the `contentread` table with a double WHERE clause of `userid` and `contentid`.

```
$userid = $vbulletin->userinfo[userid];
$chkthread = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contentread WHERE userid = '$userid' AND contentid = 1");
$chkthr = mysql_num_rows($chkthread);
if($chkthr < 1){
}
```

Comment: Answering your own questions? lol nice one does it work the way you wanted it to?

Comment: Yep it does exactly what I want it to do.